# Как сделать запись атрибута href в куки? (Смена стилей на сайте)

Tags: jquery, cookie

Всем привет! Не могу побороть данную проблему из-за нехватки знаний.
Мне необходимо менять цветовые схемы на сайте, что бы после перезагрузки страницы все сохранялось.

Как это работает на сайте, смотрите тут: https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/demo/devblog/

**Вот так выглядит окошко с кнопками в index.html**

```
    <!-- *****CONFIGURE STYLE (REMOVE ON YOUR PRODUCTION SITE)****** -->
<div id="config-panel" class="config-panel d-none d-lg-block">
    <div class="panel-inner">
        <a id="config-trigger" class="config-trigger config-panel-hide text-center" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin mx-auto" data-fa-transform="down-6"></i></a>
        <h5 class="panel-title">Choose Colour</h5>
        <ul id="color-options" class="list-inline mb-0">
            <li class="theme-1 active list-inline-item"><a data-style="{THEME}/css/main.css" href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="theme-2  list-inline-item"><a data-style="{THEME}/css/main-2.css" href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="theme-3  list-inline-item"><a data-style="{THEME}/css/main-3.css" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <a id="config-close" class="close" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--//panel-inner-->
</div>
<script src="{THEME}/js/StyleSwitcher/style-switcher.js"></script>
<!--//configure-panel-->

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{THEME}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**При каком либо выборе в менюшке выше, меняется атрибут href вот тут.**

```
    <link id="theme-style" rel="stylesheet" href="{THEME}/css/main.css" />
```

**Управляет всем этим делом JS и библиотека jQuery v3.3.1**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    /* ======= DEMO THEME CONFIG ====== */
    $('#config-trigger').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        //$("#config-panel").toggleClass('config-panel-open');

        if($(this).hasClass('config-panel-open')){
          $("#config-panel").animate({
            right: "-=190" //same as the panel width
           }, 500);
          $(this).removeClass('config-panel-open').addClass('config-panel-hide');
         }
         else {      
         $("#config-panel").animate({
           right: "+=190" //same as the panel width
           }, 500);
          $(this).removeClass('config-panel-hide').addClass('config-panel-open');    
         }
    });

    $('#config-close').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#config-trigger').click();
    });


    $('#color-options a').on('click', function(e) { 
        var $styleSheet = $(this).attr('data-style');

        $('#theme-style').attr('href', $styleSheet);

        var $listItem = $(this).closest('li');
        $listItem.addClass('active');
        $listItem.siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();


    });


});
```

Основная проблема, что после обновления страницы, устанавливается стандартный стиль main.css, а нужно сохранить выбранный юзером стиль. **Помогите решить эту проблему!**

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: Друже, я плохо шарю во всем этом, мне бы применить данный метод к существующему. Я не смогу сам дописать скрипт, мне нужно решение.